# Specify variable as a value for starts with regex operator '^'

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to specify a variable string as input for the '^' when writing a regex?

So if you have the following list of strings:
`testlist = ['access-list something something', 'something access-list']`

There is a line of code that works when called like this:

`NAT_acls = parse.find_objects(r^'access-list')`

This code parses a configuration file and returns all the strings that begin with "access-list".

I want to use a variable string that is checked when the above line is called, so only access lists with a specific name are returned. So I can do something like this:

`acl_name = ''.join(['access-list',' ',some_acl_name])
NAT_acls = parse.find_objects(^acl_name)`

This code doesn't work. Is there a way to use the "^" operator with a variable? I've looked at the documentation, but I'm none the wiser.

Comment: Like `NAT_acls = parse.find_objects(r"^{}".format(re.escape(acl_name)))`?

Comment: You are a magician! Care to explain why my code doesn't work please? It would be really useful for a newbie like me to understand this. I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Or why something like:
'''
NAT_acls = parse.find_objects(r"^{}".format(acl_name))
'''
Won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you seek is

```
NAT_acls = parse.find_objects(r"^{}".format(re.escape(acl_name)))
```

The `r"^{}"` will be populated with the escaped `acl_name` string. If it contains special regex metacharacters, the results you get with the regex might be not what you expect (as `.` matches any character but a newline, `+` matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern, etc.).

The `^` will have the regex engine look for a match at the start of the string.